# How to use qgis to get fraction of different vegetation types in a grid?

Tags: qgis, raster, land-classification, land-use

I have a vector file having different land use type. I have to create grid in that and the grid should be similar to a raster file. Finally I have to calculate fraction of each land cover type with a grid. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Generate vector layer that represents that grid, than you can use **Vector polygon tools -> Intersection**. Result will be your base layer where polygons are split on on grid element borders. Now you can calculate area of this polygons and calculate what you need.